# Getting Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, async-await

I wonder why I am getting this err/warning even though my code looks okay.

Here's the UserModel I started building:

```
const fs = require('fs');

class UserModel {
    constructor(filename) {
        if (!filename) {
            throw new Error('Require a filename...');
        }
        this.file = filename;
        try{
            fs.accessSync(this.file);   //to check if the file exists already   
        } catch (err) {                 //if not, make a new file
            fs.writeFileSync(this.file, ['']);             
        }
    }

    async getAll() {    
        return JSON.parse(await fs.promises.readFile(this.file,{
            encoding: 'utf8'
        }));
    }
}

//to test the above code
const test = async () => {
    const user = new UserModel('users.json');
    const data = await user.getAll();
    console.log(data);
}
test();
```

Please help, new to NodeJS world.

Comment: Use `test().catch(console.error)`, or place a `try`/`catch` around the `getAll` call in the `test` function.

Comment: Getting warning because of `test()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment says, you should put a `try`/`catch` around the `await` in `getAll`. Like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

class UserModel {
    constructor(filename) {
        if (!filename) {
            throw new Error('Require a filename...');
        }
        this.file = filename;
        try{
            fs.accessSync(this.file);   //to check if the file exists already   
        } catch (err) {                 //if not, make a new file
            fs.writeFileSync(this.file, ['']);             
        }
    }

    async getAll() {
        return JSON.parse(await fs.promises.readFile(this.file,{
            encoding: 'utf8'
        }));
    }
}

//to test the above code
const test = async () => {
    const user = new UserModel('users.json');
    try {
        const data = await user.getAll();
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error.stack)
    }
}
test();
```

Comment: No, my comment suggested it should be placed *around* the `getAll()` call, not *inside* the `getAll`  function

Comment: You also removed the json parsing

Comment: Good call. Edited the answer. This approach should take care of the unhandled promise rejection warning as well.

Comment: @psehgal the point of Bergi suggesting moving the error handling outside `getAll()` is separation of concerns. The `getAll()` method does not, and _should not_ know how the error should be handled, only the caller does, so the caller should handle the error instead. You're also duplicating error handling this way because say the inner error gets handled, `getAll()` returns `Promise<undefined>`, and `data` in `test` becomes `undefined`, which leads to another error, ad infinitum.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see what you mean. Yes, I agree that that's a better design. I will update my answer for OP.

Comment: I understand all the comments here, **but what's the solution** for this? If anyone could help.